# Problem with Action/Func delegates in VS 2019

Tags: c#, delegates, func

I tried to make a program that reads from the console a sequence of numbers and then prints only the even ones in sorting order. The problem is that when I try to remove a number from the array in the delegate it does NOT work. I know there are much simpler ways of making the program, but I want to learn more about delegates and events. If you guys can help me with this(or have any information about the topic) it would be extremely helpful. Thanks!!!

My code:

```
 Func<int, bool> checkIfEven = num => num % 2 == 0;

        Action<int[]> sortArray = arr => Console.WriteLine(arr.Max() + " ");

        Func<List<int>, int> findMaxIndex = num => num.IndexOf(num.Max());    
        
        int[] numbers = Console.ReadLine().Split(" ").Select(int.Parse).Where(checkIfEven).ToArray();

        Action<List<int>> removeMax = list => list.RemoveAt(findMaxIndex(numbers.ToList()));

        while (numbers.Length>0)
        { 
            sortArray(numbers);
            removeMax(numbers.ToList());
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is in this line:

`removeMax(numbers.ToList());`

This call: `numbers.ToList()` creates a **new list** from `numbers` array so when `removeMax` is called it removes an element from a list which is a **copy of array** `numbers` not the `numbers` array itself as it was probably intended.

Comment: Yeah, I supposed something like that could happen. So how can I do it?

Comment: @ДаниелЙорданов Just use one structure, either array or list. If you choose `List<int>` there should be only one `ToList()` call, namely: `.Where(checkIfEven).ToList();`. Remove the rest of `ToList()` and it will work. NB: `ToList()` creates a new list by copying elements from its argument (be it an array or another list), so do it once and then just pass resulting list everywhere so it can be modified. But as for your original question: there is nothing wrong with your delegates (except for the mix of arrays and lists).

Comment: Thank you for your help!!!